# Cannot access remote network after connecting to VPN | Window7

Tags: windows-7, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I am using Cisco VPN client (5.0.07.0290) on my window7 machine (64 bit) to connect to the VPN network of my client.
VPN client connection status is shown as "connected", but when I am trying to open any resource / URL within that network, I am getting connection timeout error.

I used the same VPN client on another machine with window7 and everything is working fine, I am not sure what can be the root cause for this issue.

I have already checked following things

1. Window firewall is disabled.
2. Antivirus is disabled.

### Update

I have also tried with SHREW and it is showing as connected but unable to open any URL or resource through the VPN network, seems like the issue is with my machine (Window7)

Can any one point me what might be the possible root cause for this?

Comment: can you verify whether your office network blocking any IP series in NAT level and also check whether your windows 7 machine is running with DHCP or static IP?

Comment: @vembutech: I have already checked this by installing same client on another machine and its working fine, both the machines are in the same office netoowrk

Comment: I've had this with virtual network adapters for VMs: a static subnet configured for some arbitrary 192.168.0.0/16 network that conflicted with the VPN's network. does `route print` show anything that might conflict that's preventing you from routing through the VPN?

Comment: Did you [check Peer response timeout](https://vpnreg.ucs.ed.ac.uk/access/ciscotimeout.html) ?

Comment: What is your local subnet?  What is the remote subnet?  Do you have any adapters configured locally with the same subnet as the remote subnet?  If so, you might find that the packets are being placed on a local adapter rather than routing through the vpn.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue as well. Here is what I did:

- Rename/Delete the `hosts` file
- Use APIPA to configure a fallback static IP for your DHCP connection
- Use the router configuration to allow tunneling
- Use the browser preferences to setup a VPN proxy server PAC file
- Use the Windows Services configuration to enable the Secure Socket Tunneling Protocol Service

**References**

- [Windows 7: Alternate IP Address](http://windowstipoftheday.blogspot.com/2011/03/windows-7-alternate-ip-address.html)
- [Understanding Web Proxy Configuration](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/10/11/web-proxy-configuration-and-ie11-changes.aspx)
- [Microsoft TCP/IP Host Name Resolution Order](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172218/)
- [Cisco VPN Client FAQ](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/vpn-client/45102-vpnclientfaq.html)
- [Secure Socket Tunneling Protocol Service](http://www.blackviper.com/windows-services/secure-socket-tunneling-protocol-service/)
- [PAC Best Practices](http://www.websense.com/content/support/library/web/v76/pac_file_best_practices/PAC_best_pract.aspx)